# How to using formatted variables with placeholder with inputted text by a user?

Tags: python-3.x, variables, placeholder

How to using formatted variables with placeholder with inputted text by a user?

Maybe the question is not very precise but I learn Python from the book, and books as usually have a pure text without examples. However, I would like to achieve this kind of pattern:

`**** Word ****`

1. `Word` - is inputted text by user
2. `*` - is depend of how many characters have got a inputted Word (in this example Word consist 4 characters. Hence, 4 stars)
3. As you see Word is preceded by asterisks and there are spaces at the beginning and end of the word.

So, this is my code:

```
word = input()
x = 2 + 3 * len(word)       # <---Lenght of the word * 3 + 2 spaces
print("{:*^x}".format(word))
```

Hence, I have error. X in `{:*^x}` is in int(),  but in bracket is treated as str() object. How to exclude it? Any `print("{:x^"x"}"` will be treated as well as an error. This is a first question. Second question is, how to achieve spaces before and after text. I can't in `.format()` add `" "` twice.

Error is: `ValueError: Unknown format code 'x' for object of type 'str'`

For any solutions, suggestion I'll be very appreciated. However, I'm on the beginning level so any simple solution is welcome.
Thank you!

I have tried many methods, but have had no success.

Comment: Hmm, I just modify code for this one:

```
word = input()
x = 2 + 3 * len(word)
print("*{:^{}}*".format(word, x))
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. Just walk with dog give a solution.
The correct code is:

```
word = input()
x = len(word)
print("*" * x + " {} ".format(word) + "*" * x)
```